# Elasticsearch curator delete the whole index instead of older documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I have an index which contains data for 1 year.
I want to delete the older data and keep the last 60 days.

I tried with delete_query which seems to work but it's VERY time consuming.

It seems "curator" is the best way to do this.

So, I made this configuration :

```
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Delete indices older than 60 days.
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: myindex*
    - filtertype: age
      source: field_stats
      direction: older
      unit: days
      unit_count: 60
      field: '@timestamp'
      stats_result: min_value
```

and launch it with curator cli.

Versions : curator 5.8 and elasticsearch 6.5

The result is not the one expected !

If there is data older than 60 days, the WHOLE index is dropped instead of only the data older than 60 days.
Can you help me with that please ?

Answer (score 1):

Curator only deletes entire indices. This has always been the case from the beginning. You have two options: stick with delete by query, or split your data into multiple indices to expire it over time in chunks (entire indices). Because rollover indices are backed by a single alias, your searches will still see the entire data set (when searching using the alias).

Comment: Ok thank you ! Do you have some example to make this happend ? or some links ?